# Show all iTunes iOS apps that aren't installed on any devices

Tags: itunes, ios, ipad, applications, ipod-touch

I've got an iPod Touch and an iPad, both connected to iTunes on the same computer. So, they share the same iOS app library in iTunes.

How can I quickly see which apps are not installed in either the iPad or iPod Touch, without having to switch back and forth between the devices, in iTunes?

I'd like to clean the apps by removing all apps that aren't installed on any of my devices. I've got hundreds of apps in iTunes but only a fraction of those are actually installed in my devices. Normally I wouldn't bother cleaning them, but there are a lot of big games that I don't have installed, and I like to keep my iTunes on my SSD, which has a limited amount of space.

Comment: I'm curious why you sync them at all with iTunes?

Comment: Isn't it common to sync iOS devices with a computer running iTunes? Sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a walkthrough solution here, which seems easy and comprehensive.
http://blog.macsales.com/17825-an-easy-way-to-clear-out-unused-ios-apps-from-itunes-11

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.